# Regex or without grouping

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want to get the thread-id of an url via regex.

The Url can have these states:

1. https://mypage.com/threads/an-example-thread/
2. https://mypage.com/threads/an-example-thread/page-1
3. https://mypage.com/threads/an-example-thread

My pattern `.+/threads/(.+)/.+` covers the first two options. Now I need a pattern, that also covers option 3. `.+/threads/(.+)(/.+|$)` works. But I use the first group to get the tread-id/name. So how is is possible to create an or-pattern without grouping?

Comment: `(/.+|$)` => `(?:/.+|$)`?

Comment: Why not just [`/threads/([^\/]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/TEGwy4/1)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a non-capturing group in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, try to use  `/threads/([^\/]*)`, that will match all 3.